# What is the different in the lambda expression from group1 and group2?

Tags: c#

What is the difference between Group1 and Group2 in the following syntax. I have just started using these types of expressions and I see one that has a delegate and looks like a function (for the most part) and then I see Group1 (`=>`) with this syntax and I'm not certain which is different or which is better.

It also says that `Func<>` should only take two arguments but in Group1 example it takes three variables. Why is that?
        [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
       Group1

        Action<bool> print1 = q => Console.WriteLine(q);
        Action<int> printInt = q => Console.WriteLine(q);
        Func<double, double> square1 = c => c * c;
        Func<double, double, double> add1 = (x, y) => x + y;
        Predicate<double> isLessThanTen1 = f => f < 10;

       Group2

        Func<string, string> convert = delegate(string s)
        { 
            return s.ToUpper(); 
        };
```

Comment: "It also says that Func should only take two arguements but in Group1 example it takes three variables." The third argument in Func signature represents the return value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group 1 is a shorthand way of creating a delegate, without the need for delegate(). It's "preferred" because it's shorter and easier to read.

- Action<> is a delegate that takes an argument (or multiple) and returns void
- Func<> is a delegate that takes an argument (or multiple) and returns something
- Predicate<> is a delegate that takes an argument (or multiple) and returns bool

In other words

```
Func<int, void> == Action<int>
```

and

```
Func<int, bool> == Predicate<int>
```

In the MSDN page you linked to, there's other overloads of Func<> that take a varying amount of parameters. For example, [here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534303(v=vs.110).aspx) a version that accepts 4 parameters.

One of the best resources on the topic is [C# in Depth](http://csharpindepth.com/) by [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet). It gives a nice history of delegates and the syntax changes in each version of C#.

Comment: I will have to look in to that book.  You can have as many statements in the delegate as any other function correct?